# Change video currentTime to element mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Basically I'm working at creating a custom control for my videos, I don't wanna use any other library or any other source from my videos totally self made. So Currently I'm working on creating the seek bar for video where when the user click on a specific position of a `div` box, I need to calculate mouse click position and change video `currentTime` to that value.

My Script:

```
function vidseek(){
    var nt=(100/vid.duration)*vid.currentTime;
    $('.skbdur').css('width', nt+"%");
    var skbwidth=$('.skbdur').width()-5;
    $('.skbtd').css({left: skbwidth});
}

$('.sekbar').click(function(e){
    var posX = $(this).offset().left;
    var xpos=e.pageX-posX;
    var seekto=Math.floor((xpos/vid.duration)*100);
    console.log(seekto+" "+xpos + " posX "+posX+" E: "+e.pageX);
    vid.currentTime=seekto;
});
```

The problem is that when The user click at the seekbar position 170 the video jump to 152, So far I can tell is that the problem is in my calculation at line `var seekto=Math.floor()` which is not the proper way of calculation for video timing.

Console Output: `Seekto: 153 xpos: 262.3499755859375 posX: 793.6500244140625 E: 1056`

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to properly calculate mouse position click to make video jump to that specific position.

Comment: why cant you use the html input range in place of some other elements?

Comment: @jafarbtech I am sorry I didn't replied you soon enough, Had to do some research about it. anyway with `range` element can we change background color of range seek bar while buffered, buffering and video left?